# Several "equations" in the same line

Tags: equations

```
\begin {eqnarray}
P(N(t)=n)=P(T_{n}\leq t)- P(T_{n+1}\leq t)=e^{-\lambda*t}*\frac {(\lamda*t)^{n}}{n!}
\end {eqnarray}
```

I want to write this in latex however and it gives me an error, can I help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a minimal *compîlable* code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error is due to a typo, lamda instead of lambda

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray`; in this case use `equation`. Fix the typo and you'll be OK. In future questions, please add information about the errors you get.

Comment: As for why `eqnarray` is bad, see the links in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/156366).

Answer (score 0):

Error cleared (`\lamda` replaced with `\lambda`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin {equation}
P(N(t)=n)=P(T_{n}\leq t)- P(T_{n+1}\leq t)=e^{-\lambda*t}*\frac {(\lambda*t)^{n}}{n!}
\end {equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `eqnarray` is not to be used. In this case `equation` is the best choice.